# Nested bootstrap grid - layout issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a struggle with bootstrap framework.
I want to create a simple box with image on the left side and some text and other elements on the right side. 
But having issue when it is displayed on small screens.

[This is my current code.](http://jsfiddle.net/TSWa6/)

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="margin-top: 3px;">
            <div class="feed-box">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <img style="max-width: 52px;" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=250">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <div class="row">
                            <p><a href="#">John Doe</a> announced something</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <p>
Per the documentation, nesting is easy—just put a row of columns within an existing column. This gives you two columns starting at desktops and scaling to large desktops, with another two (equal widths) within the larger column.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <a href="#">Comment</a>
                            <a href="#">Share</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I will explain it through images:
**Desktop (it's fine this padding is not important here)**:
[image]
**Small screen (bad)**:
[image]
**What I am trying to make (in small screens)**:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to style the elements for small screen.

For example check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/TSWa6/1/)**(resize to see the difference)

CSS used

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
    .feed-box .col-md-1{
      float:left;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    }
    .feed-box .col-md-11{
      margin-top:15px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to also specify the cols for smaller screens...i.e - you don't need to put in for md

```
<div class = "row">
   <div class = "col-sm-1">
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-11">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jame's way will work; this is the more correct bootstrap answer.